# Unable to change say voice in Tropo MVC

Tags: tropo

I'm using the Tropo MVC classes and have a problem with changing the voice in the say. Setting the voice property of the say object does not seem to change the voice for example:

```
                Say say1 = new Say("This is first voice");
                say1.Voice = "susan";
                Say say2 = new Say("This is the male voice");
                say2.Voice = "dave";
                List<Say> sayList = new List<Say>();
                sayList.Add(say1);
                sayList.Add(say2);
                Script.Ask(null, null, new Choices("[1 DIGIT]", "dtmf", "#"), null, strArgs, true, sayList, Convert.ToSingle(action.Timeout));
```

The voice does not change. In fact it appears that the only way to change the voice is to set Script.Voice = "voice" which doesn't work for me as I have to handle language select in the first Ask which requires English voice followed by French voice.

Comment: Support at Tropo clarified that multiple says are for having the system say something different depending on specific events. To achieve English followed by another language in a different voice you should use an Ask with an immediate timeout followed by the next Ask in the different voice. I tested this approach and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tropo also supports [SSML](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/), which is a super powerful markup language for mixing voices and adjusting voice tempo/cadence.

You can mix voices in a single Say command by doing something like:

```
new Say("<?xml version='1.0'?><speak>For English please press 1.<voice name='Carlos' xml:lang='es'>para el español por favor pulse 2</voice></speak>")
```

The inline XML is kinda yukkie but it gets the job done and learning SSML will allow you to create some really professional-sounding apps.

Comment: But you are totally changing the voice correct? And if I need to say english terms in a portuguese sentence for example?